# Node.js/ES6 - Unable to call a promise and return value from a function

Tags: node.js, function, es6-promise

I have the following function:

```
const getRemote = function getRemote() {

  request.make(url)
      .then(function (data) {
          return data;

      })
      .catch(function (err) {
          log.error("Error loading external config file: " + err);
      });
};

exports.getRemote = getRemote;
```

I would like to export the result of `data`. `request.make()` returns a promise, however my function returns `undefined`.

If I `return request.make(url)...` I get a promise response as follows:

`Promise {
  _bitField: 0,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
  _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
  _progressHandler0: undefined,
  _promise0: undefined,
  _receiver0: undefined,
  _settledValue: undefined }`

How can I export the value of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return request.make(url)` is the correct thing to do. That returns the promise, which is what you want to have access to outside the module, so that you can do something like:

```
yourModule.getRemote().then( data => {
    // use data here
} );
```